# Where can I find quarterly/monthly medicare/medicaid state level drug utilization data

Tags: microeconomics, data-request

I read a paper titled 'State generic substitution laws can lower drug outlays under
medicaid'. It uses quarterly state level medicaid drug utilization data. However, I could only find yearly data at the state level. Has anyone has experience in this data set.

Comment: Please link the paper, they should have it listed and you just missed the citation.

Comment: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20606192 The link is here. I checked their references.Their link no longer works.

Comment: You might want to call the Center for Medicare and Medicaid Services directly and ask them about why the link is broken.

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer. By god, if I knew a specific source for some data and the source was offline, the very first place I would ask would be the provider of the data, not an unrelated online Q&A site.